# Twig syntaxe : Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "."

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.2

I'm trying to assign an object to a form property :

```
{% if form.person is not defined %}
    {%- set form.person = form.fatherContact -%}
{% endif %}
```

But I'm getting this error :

> Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block"
>   expected).

What's wrong with my code ? According to the [twig documentation](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/set.html), this is how we assign a variable so I don't get it. Maybe it's because the `person` property does not exist ?

Thx

Comment: You can't set object properties inside twig by default

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried to merge the property but then the form become an instance of array and not a formview anymore so it doesn't work

Comment: Why are you doing this in your 'template layer', this logic should not be in twig ...